# Modelica - Change default Medium in extending model (Dymola)

Tags: inheritance, documentation, modelica, dymola

I would like to change the default Medium in an extending model such that the new value is shown in the "documentation" tab. For example:

```
partial model A
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
  ...
end A;

model B
  extends A;
  ...
end B;

model C
  extends B(
    redeclare replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
  ...
end C;
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out why the documentation of model C still says the default value for Medium is PartialMedium or how i could change this behaviour!
The same thing happens when I try to redefine models.

(One example would be a class inherited from Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe which sets different default values for the Medium package or HeatTransfer and FlowModel models)

I need to define these values in the model (C) since i am trying to model a heating circuit with ~80 pipes and do not want to define these values over and over again.

Is it possible to clean up the documentation somehow?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the tool are using, but since you put the Dymola tag on the question, I'm going to assume it is Dymola.

This is really a question for the Dymola support desk.  I don't have any great insight about the internal workings of Dymola that would give me a clue about how to get it to recognize the default that you want.  However, you might try this approach with your model (untested):

```
model C
  replaceable package MyMedium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater
  extends B(
    redeclare package Medium = MyMedium);
  ...
end C;
```

This establishes a new class (and default value).  Perhaps that would be sufficient in your case?

You might also try something like this as well (to establish a new constraining type):

```
model C
  extends B(
    redeclare replaceable package Medium =
        Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby
        Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
  ...
end C;
```

(again, untested)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Unfortunately both approaches do not fix the issue =/ I will try the Dymola support desk! and add the solution then!